# Is $\left\{x\mid x\text{ is a countable set}\right\}$ a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this question in an exam:

Is $\left\{x\mid x\text{ is a  countable set}\right\}$ a set?

We are working in ${\sf ZFC}$.

Comment: No, it is not .

Comment: For every set $x$ in the universe, $\{x\}$ is even a finite set.

Comment: Is that meant to be the set of all countable sets?

Comment: No, it's not even an allowed definition in ZFC, since the separation axioms require the lefthand side to be a set, and all there is no such thing as the set of all sets.

Comment: @level1807 But that's not a sufficient argument. The *set* $H(\aleph_1)$ is defined as the collection of *all* sets whose transitive closure has countable size. The difference is subtle.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo interesting. So what is the strict way of defining $H(\aleph_1)$? Does it avoid the usage of the separation axiom schema somehow?

Comment: @level1807 There are several approaches. One is to realize that any element of $H(\aleph_1)$ can be coded as a certain "tree" on $\omega$, and use replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T_1=\lbrace x \mid x \text{ is countable} \rbrace$ is a set, so
is $T_2=\lbrace x \mid x \text{ is a singleton} \rbrace$ by the axiom
of subsets, so is $T_3=\lbrace x  \mid x \text{ is a set} \rbrace$ by the axiom of replacement,
but it is well known that $T_3$ is not a set( if it was, by
the axiom of subsets we could form $T_4=\lbrace x \mid x\not\in x\rbrace$
and this would be [Russell’s paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)).

Comment: Probably you meant to write $T_3=\{x\mid x=x\}=\{x\mid x$ is a set$\}$ or some such. As written, $T_3$ is a singleton, which is not what you meant.

Comment: You don't really need the Axiom of Replacement here.

Answer (score 7):

If the set of all countable sets existed, then by the axiom of unions, the union of all countable sets would exist. That would be the whole universe, since everything belongs to some countable set, e.g., $x\in\omega\cup\{x\}$. But there is no universal set; for every set $S$, the set $\{x\in S:x\notin x\}$ does not belong to $S$.

Answer (score 2):

This [axiom](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AxiomofSubsets.html)

can only be applied in the form
$$
\{x \in X \colon x \text{ is countable}\}
$$
for a given set $X$. So what you give is not a valid definition for a set.

However this does not itself prove that there not exists a set with the property you have stated (i.e. that contains all countable sets).